# ng-bind-html not working in my context

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using `ngBindHtml` directive for append the HTML in AngularJS. It is appending but not as expected some area tag attributes not properly added in the `div`.

So the `onclick` event in the area tag is not working. first of all it is not append in the html but in the I am using jQuery `.html()` it's working fine.
I want the answer in Angular approach.

## HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="editor"></div>
```

## Controller

```
 $scope.editor =  "<p>
      <img alt="how to measure" name="shirtguidemeasure" src="http://www.jcpenney.com/dotcom/images/2013_09_SHIRT_TAB1_HOW_TO_MEASURE.jpg" style="width: 620px; height: auto" usemap="#imgmap201310911202" />
      <map id="imgmap201310911202" name="imgmap201310911202">
        <area _fcksavedurl="test" alt="how to measure" coords="5,4,153,31" onclick="document.images.shirtguidemeasure.src='/mobile/images/2013_09_SHIRT_TAB1_HOW_TO_MEASURE.jpg';" shape="rectangle" style="display: block; cursor: pointer" title="how to measure" />
        <area _fcksavedurl="test" alt="classic" coords="157,4,306,31" onclick="document.images.shirtguidemeasure.src='/mobile/images/2013_09_SHIRT_TAB2_CLASSIC.jpg';" shape="rectangle" style="display: block; cursor: pointer" title="classic" />
        <area _fcksavedurl="test" alt="slim" coords="310,3,459,31" onclick="document.images.shirtguidemeasure.src='/mobile/images/2013_09_SHIRT_TAB3_SLIM.jpg';" shape="rectangle" style="display: block; cursor: pointer" title="slim" />
        <area _fcksavedurl="test" alt="big and tall" coords="464,3,617,31" onclick="document.images.shirtguidemeasure.src='/mobile/images/2013_09_SHIRT_TAB4_BIG_TALL.jpg';" shape="rectangle" style="display: block; cursor: pointer" title="big and tall" />
      </map>
     </p>";
```

## Output

```
<div ng-bind-html="editor" class="ng-binding">
<p>
<img alt="how to measure" src="http://www.jcpenney.com/dotcom/images/2013_09_SHIRT_TAB1_HOW_TO_MEASURE.jpg" usemap="#imgmap201310911202">
<map>
<area alt="how to measure" coords="5,4,153,31" shape="rectangle" title="how to measure">
<area alt="classic" coords="157,4,306,31" shape="rectangle" title="classic">
<area alt="slim" coords="310,3,459,31" shape="rectangle" title="slim">
<area alt="big and tall" coords="464,3,617,31" shape="rectangle" title="big and tall">
</map>
</p>
</div>
```

In the output Missing area tag attributes `onclick="document.images.shirtguidemeasure.src` and styles.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: @Mast - Thanks for editing I approved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-bind-html` is doing a sanitization using `$sanitize` service. As part of it some unsafe tokens are removed from the output. In older versions of Angular you could use `ng-bing-html-unsafe` instead:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="editor"></div>
```

This directive does not exist in later versions of angular, so you need to explicitly trust value via $sce.trustAsHtml. See the example under [Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#show-me-an-example-using-sce-).

In this case in your controller you need to add a dependency for `$sce` and use it to mark HTML as safe:

```
angular.module('mySceApp', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('AppController', function($scope, $sce) {
            $scope.editor = $sce.trustAsHtml('YOUR UNSAFE HTML GOES HERE');
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing single and double quotes usages, 
plus HTML on multiple lines should be quoted:

```
$scope.editor =  
  '<p>'+
  '<h1 style="color: red;">MY HEADER</h1>'+
  '</p>';
```